# What is meant by Not Tracked in Git / Sourcetree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I've coded lot of changes also created new components. Now I've to commit all these. But I  faced something new when I went to source tree. There are changes I've to commit but whenever I hovered over newly created components I saw "Not tracked". Don't know what is this and how to handle this.

Comment: Git doesn't notice your new files unless you "add" them to your repository. The console command is `git add my_file.txt`, or assuming you use some graphical application, there should be a similar button or option to add your files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Not tracked" simply means that Git doesn't have a record of those files—they have never been committed nor have they been added to the staging area.

From the [Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository):

> Remember that each file in your working directory can be in one of two states: **tracked** or **untracked**. Tracked files are files that were in the last snapshot, as well as any newly staged files; they can be unmodified, modified, or staged. In short, tracked files are files that Git knows about.
>
> Untracked files are everything else — any files in your working directory that were not in your last snapshot and are not in your staging area.

[Adding the files to staging area](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#_tracking_files) with `git add` is enough for Git to start tracking them and show them as "new".

Answer (score 0):

Newly created components are still on local. hence they are not tracked. Once you commit and push your changes to server. component or files will be tracked hereafter.